# android app crashing before starting 2nd activity

Tags: android, arduino

Hey guys I'm trying to fix it long ago I'm seeking help here before giving it up.. I don't know whats wrong with handler.. I'm trying to send some integer from arduino to android..

**ARDUINO SKETCH:**

```
  void sendAndroidValues()
 {
  //puts # before the values so app knows what to do with the data
  Serial.print('#');
  //for loop cycles through 4 sensors and sends values via serial
  Serial.print(digitalRead(5));
    Serial.print('+');
    //technically not needed but I prefer to break up data values
 Serial.print('~'); //used as an end of transmission character - used in app for string length
 Serial.println();
 delay(1000);        //added a delay to eliminate missed transmissions
}
```

**ANDROID**

```
private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

        textView1.setText("Connecting...");
        // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the
        // View
        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

        Intent i = new Intent(DeviceListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);
        startActivity(i);
    }
};
```

ACTIVITY WHICH IS CRASHING BEFORE STARTING... any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

```
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "run()---before",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        int bytes;

        // Keep looping to listen for received messages
        while (true) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "while true",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "in try",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); // read bytes from input
                                                    // buffer
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes); // Send
                                                                    // the
                // obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1,
                        readMessage).sendToTarget();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "listner noonononononononononon",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "listner eror",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you added second activity in your manifest?

Comment: Yes I did, I have added second Activity in manifest.

Comment: could you please post the logcat too..

Comment: If I don't call bluetoothIn = new Handler() it works fine...

Comment: why dont youpost the logcat?

Comment: did you correctly imported Handler.you should import it like this:
import android.os.Handler;
android has two option for importing handler class

Comment: Lal logcat is empty, I just Export the project and transfer the apk file to phone and then test it after installing ..

Comment: Yes it is imported as you said import android.os.Handler;

Comment: @Asad  Instead of doing that, just plug your droid to your PC enable USB debugging form developer in settings down the bottom and run it. Afterwards you will be able to view the logcat on the bottom of Android Studio

Comment: What bluetooth module are you using?

Comment: HC-O5 is the bluetooth module which I'm using...